# Sorting data from a join chronologically to get most recent entry

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, mariadb

I have 3 Database Tables:

- OpenROHeader
- OpenROData
- OpenRONotes

Header & Data are updated (overwritten) hourly while Notes are added manually and linked via a field "RO_Number"

What I want the SQL to do is retrieve the most current "Notes" (by 'date_updated')

```
SELECT file_date, rod.id as id, key_id, key_name, key_value, DATE_FORMAT(expected_close_date , '%d/%m/%y' ) as expected_close_date, wty_dept
FROM OpenROHeader roh 
JOIN OpenROData rod ON roh.id=rod.header_id 
LEFT JOIN OpenRONotes ron ON rod.key_value=ron.ro_number 
WHERE roh.customer_id='193' 
GROUP BY key_id, key_name
```

There are 2 entries in Notes table - I want the most recent:

```
id, customer_id, ro_number, expected_close_date, advisor_notes, wty_dept, date_updated
4059, 193, 'S117986', NULL, 'WTY_ON<br>- S.W.', 'on', '2018-09-24 05:02:45'
4060, 193, 'S117986', NULL, 'WTY_OFF<br>- S.A.', NULL, '2018-09-24 05:03:24'
```

I want it to return data (last 2 columns) in SELECT from row with id 4060 NOT 4059

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f00326/1/0

But instead of returning most current 'wty_dept' (NULL) from 2018-09-24 05:03:24

My SQL statement is returning the previous entry 'on' from 2018-09-24 05:02:45 (older)

How can I sort a join to return most recent data

Comment: What are you expecting the GROUP BY in that query to actually do?

Comment: What version of mySQL. Row_Number is the way to go if you are at the latest version.

Comment: Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.0.36-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10

Comment: Ok, that should have it all then. But your description mentions dates that are not in your sample data in the fiddle. I've had a go at an answer but I think the check for not exists probably needs some refinement.

Comment: GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved, how come?

Comment: @TomC The date is in the table but not being selected

Comment: Thanks I see it now. Think my answer should work then. It does get the row you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to sort, just make sure there is not a later comment. I've made assumptions about how we look up the notes, but assuming I have it correct, this should do it for you (UPDATED after I think I understood your requirements!)

```
SELECT file_date, advisor_notes, rod.id as id, key_id, key_name, key_value, DATE_FORMAT(expected_close_date , '%d/%m/%y' ) as expected_close_date, wty_dept
FROM OpenROHeader roh 
JOIN OpenROData rod ON roh.id=rod.header_id 
LEFT JOIN OpenRONotes ron ON rod.key_value=ron.ro_number 
WHERE roh.customer_id='193' 
and not exists (select * from OpenRONotes ron2 where rod.key_value=ron2.ro_number and ron2.date_updated>ron.date_updated)
```

Answer (score 0):

put desc after group by clouse
for example-
SELECT * from student GROUP BY section desc;
it will g

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most recent column from join of three tables as:

```
SELECT file_date, rod_id AS id, key_id, key_name, key_value, DATE_FORMAT(expected_close_date , '%d/%m/%y' ) AS expected_close_date, wty_dept
FROM OpenROHeader roh
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT rod.id rod_id ,key_id,key_name ,key_value ,expected_close_date ,wty_dept ,header_id,date_updated
FROM OpenROData rod
RIGHT OUTER JOIN OpenRONotes ron 
ON rod.key_value=ron.ro_number 
ORDER BY ron.date_updated ) tab 
ON roh.id=header_id WHERE 1=1 AND
roh.customer_id='193'
ORDER BY date_updated DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The above query returned the most recent records with column wty_dept as NULL.
Check this and enjoy coding :) !!